# Кол-во способов, которым можно вырезать прямоугольную область без закрашенных клеток

Tags: алгоритм

Олимпиадное задача, для тех, кто хочет поломать голову:)

У нас есть листок в клетку размером n на m. К клеток в нем закрашены. Требуется посчитать кол-во способов, которыми можно вырезать прямоугольную область без закрашенных клеток. способы считаются различными, если в одной прямоугольной области есть хотя бы одна клетка, которая не принадлежит другой области. разрезать можно строго по линиям:)

> `1 <= n, m <= 5000
> 1 <= k <= 100000
> 1 <= k <= n*m`

время 2 сек

Comment: > 1 <= k <= n*m

зачем это условие? или создатели задачи думают, что можно закрасить больше клеточек, чем есть на листочке?

Comment: честно, не знаю:) да и не важно, будем считать, что К не превосходит 100000

Comment: максимально возможное время выполнения программы

Comment: Мы знаем какие клетки закрашены!
у меня пока есть только такое решение:
прямоугольную область 1хМ можно m*(m+1)/2 способами разрезать, прямоугольную область Nx1 можно n*(n+1)/2. Отсюда смутный вывод: чтобы посчитать количество способов на прямоуг области NxM это будет
(n*(n+1)/2)*(m*(m+1)/2). т.е. можно свести задачу к нахождению максимальной прямоугольной области без закрашенных клеток
Если это правда, то все равно возникает одна проблема, это если мы выбираем две максимальные области, которые пересекаются, то мы считаем один и тотже вариант 2 раза

Comment: Кстати, берем максимальные размеры без закрашенных:

5000*(5000+1)/2*5000^2 = 3.125625e+014 в integer не умещается)

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста условие. Что требуется ? 

Все **возможные** наборы непересекающихся областей (т.е. [1 область из одной клетки],  [2 области каждая из одной клетки], ... [область X\*Y клеток + ... + 100 областей из одной клетки]) ?

Comment: если 1<=n , то это одномерный массив,  
клетка-это и есть прямоугольник(способы считаются различными, если в одной прямоугольной области есть хотя бы одна клетка, которая не принадлежит другой области).  
просто прогоняем массив, проверяем элемент, если клетка не закрашена-то увеличиваем счетчик.Значение счетчика-ответ.Мне кажется так.

Comment: @чипик, реализуйте и засеките время)

Comment: У меня "метод чипика" для 10000x10000 и 1000000 закрашеных клеток (каждая 1 байт, вся карта 100 мегабайт) отработал за **173 миллисекунды** (i5-2500 3.3MGz) вместе с закраской через rand() (всего 1004983 попыток покраски).

-

Очевидно в данной задаче спрашивается не про это количество прямоугольников. Я условие задачи (что все таки надо посчитать так и не понял).

Comment: Я понял задание так: нужно посчитать сколькими способами можно из данного поля выделить прямоугольную область (квадрат тоже прямоугольник), так чтобы в нее не попало ни одной закрашенной клетки. Для пустого поля по идее должно получиться n*(n+1)*m*(m+1)/4 "попыток покраски".

Comment: Тогда нужно уточнение - резать можно только с края или можно "протыкать" листок ? 

Ведь закрашенные клетки могут образовать замкнутый контур.

Comment: есть тип int64 диапазон 2^64 туда вроде вмещается)

Comment: допустим образовалась замкнутая область, тогда мы можем обрезать все что побокам и оставить только серединку(то что внутри замкнутой области)
insolor, вы правильно поняли!

Comment: > или можно "протыкать" листок ? 

@avp, по-видимому, можно)

Answer (score 1):

Где-то так:

```
count:=0;
for left:=1 to n do
begin
  for right:=left to n do
  begin
    for top:=1 to m do
    begin
      for bottom:=top to m do
      begin
        {проверяем не наехал ли нижний край на закрашенную клетку}
        {если наехал, то break}
        {если не наехал, то inc(count)}
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Алгоритм медленный, при размерах поля 100*100 выполняется уже около 2 секунд.

**UPD.** Есть такая идея:

1. Начинаем с первого столбца.
2. Проходим по столбцу вниз пока не наткнемся на закрашенную клетку.
3. Теперь "расширяем" столбец вправо, пока не наткнемся на закрашенную клетку.
4. Для полученного прямоугольника считаем варианты по формуле: `(height+1)*height/2*width`
5. Возвращаемся на левый столбец прямоугольника, перескакиваем через закрашенную клетку и переходим на пункт 3 и так пока не достигнем нижнего края.
6. Сдвигаемся на столбец вправо и опять на пункт 2

Comment: я практически полностью уверен, что решение "в лоб" с 4 вложеными циклами не уложится в 2 секунды, плюс мы изначально не знаем какие клетки закрашены

Comment: Там еще пятый вложенный цикл ("проверяем не наехал ли нижний край на закрашенную клетку") :)

Не уверен, что количество вариантов не зависит от расположения закрашенных клеток. Но если это так, то конечно должен быть более оптимальный алгоритм.

P.S. Проверил, количество вариантов зависит от расположения. Но все равно, должен быть более простой алгоритм.

Comment: Извиняюсь, надо было дописать. Мы знаем какие клетки закрашены!

Comment: подождите, т.е. изначально даны координаты закрашеных клеток?

Comment: даны:)))))

Comment: Реализовал еще пару вариантов, работают быстрее, но дают одинаковый результат только при отсутствии закрашенных клеток:) Осталось узнать какой вариант правильный и в чем неправильны остальные два)

Comment: есть тип int64 диапазон 2^64 туда вроде вмещается)